# Getting the last for loop iteration of condition in django templates

Tags: django, django-templates

I wish to add the class `rounded-t-lg shadow`on the first iteration inside the if statement, and `rounded-b-lg shadow` on the last iteration. I have the following code:

```
{% for note in notes %}
    {% if note.is_sticky %}
        <div class="flex items-center">
            <div class="{% if forloop.first %} rounded-t-lg shadow {% elif forloop.last %} rounded-b-lg shadow {% endif %}">
                <!-- code -->     
                </div>     
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

The problem that I'm running into is that forloop.last applies to the last iteration in general, and not the last iteration in the condition. So if I have three objects, where two is sticky, and the last one is not, the class will be applied to the one that is not, since its the last in "line".

How can I apply a class to the last iteration within the is_sticky condition, regardless of the objects that do not meet the condition?

Comment: I would consider annotating a flag on the queryset if possible.  The model and an explanation of the condition would help in trying to construct the annotation.

Comment: What would be the advantages of having a notes and stick_notes queryset filtering on the is_sticky field, as opposed of doing it "front-end" through a loop with condition?

Comment: I might be misunderstanding your question, but I'm not aware of a way to construct a conditional as you described in template code.  If you annotate the queryset with is_first_sticky_note and is_last_sticky_note, you can then just add that to the template: {% if note.is_first_sticky_note %}.  You could also do additional processing in the view, but it is best to do it on the queryset if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you should filter the `notes` list in your view, so it only contains those where `is_sticky == True`.  Depending on your queryset you may just need to add:

```
.filter(is_sticky=True)
```

I also think you might need to be careful of the case when there is only 1 element in `notes`.  I guess you want it to be rounded top and bottom, so you need 2 separate `if` tests, rather than an `elsif`.

```
{% for note in notes %}
  <div class="flex items-center">
    <div class="{% if forloop.first %} rounded-t-lg shadow{% endif %}{% if forloop.last %} rounded-b-lg shadow{% endif %}">
      <!-- code -->          
    </div>
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Went for this. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
{% for note in notes %}

   {% if forloop.first %}

      {% if note.is_sticky %}
        <div class="flex items-center">
            <div class="rounded-t-lg shadow">
                <!-- code -->     
                </div>     
            </div>
        </div>
      {% endif %}

   {% elif forloop.last %}

      {% if note.is_sticky %}
         <div class="flex items-center">
            <div class="rounded-b-lg shadow">
                <!-- code -->     
                </div>     
            </div>
         </div>
      {% endif %}

   {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```